# Using IF condition in MySQL after the AS

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to do this;

```
$p1 = " [ ";    
foreach($db_found->query("SELECT DISTINCT netID, count(callsign) as callcount, year(logdate) as year,
                            month(logdate)-1 as month, day(logdate) as day
              FROM NetLog
             WHERE netcall = 'CARROLL'
               AND netID <> 0

             GROUP BY netID
             ORDER BY logdate ") as $stat){ 
                 if ($stat[year] == 2017 ){
                    $p2 = "{ x: new Date($stat[year],$stat[month],$stat[day]), y: $stat[callcount] },  ";
                 }else if ($stat[year] == 2018 ){
                    $p3 = "{ x: new Date($stat[year],$stat[month],$stat[day]), y: $stat[callcount] },  ";
                 }
             }
```

But when I echo the output of $p3 all I'm getting is;

```
[ { x: new Date(2018,9,8), y: 15 }, ]
```

Can this be done in MySQL? If not how would I go about doing it?
What I'm looking for in each variable $p2 and $p3 should be like this;

```
{ x: new Date(2018,0,8), y: 8 }, { x: new Date(2018,0,15), y: 9 }, { x: new Date(2018,0,22), y: 11 }, { x: new Date(2018,0,29), y: 12 }, { x: new Date(2018,1,5), y: 11 }, { x: new Date(2018,1,12), y: 9 }, { x: new Date(2018,1,19), y: 14 }, { x: new Date(2018,1,26), y: 13 }, { x: new Date(2018,2,5), y: 11 }, { x: new Date(2018,2,12), y: 15 }, { x: new Date(2018,2,19), y: 23 }, { x: new Date(2018,2,26), y: 16 }, { x: new Date(2018,3,2), y: 17 }, { x: new Date(2018,3,9), y: 19 }, { x: new Date(2018,3,16), y: 22 }, { x: new Date(2018,3,23), y: 12 }, { x: new Date(2018,3,30), y: 20 }, { x: new Date(2018,4,7), y: 15 }, { x: new Date(2018,4,14), y: 18 }, { x: new Date(2018,4,21), y: 18 }, { x: new Date(2018,4,28), y: 22 }, { x: new Date(2018,5,4), y: 13 }, { x: new Date(2018,5,11), y: 12 }, { x: new Date(2018,5,18), y: 15 }, { x: new Date(2018,5,25), y: 19 }, { x: new Date(2018,6,2), y: 17 }, { x: new Date(2018,6,9), y: 15 }, { x: new Date(2018,6,16), y: 12 }, { x: new Date(2018,6,23), y: 13 }, { x: new Date(2018,6,30), y: 12 }, { x: new Date(2018,7,6), y: 12 }, { x: new Date(2018,7,13), y: 14 }, { x: new Date(2018,7,20), y: 16 }, { x: new Date(2018,7,27), y: 16 }, { x: new Date(2018,8,3), y: 15 }, { x: new Date(2018,8,10), y: 13 }, { x: new Date(2018,8,17), y: 19 }, { x: new Date(2018,8,24), y: 18 }, { x: new Date(2018,9,1), y: 14 }, { x: new Date(2018,9,8), y: 15 },
```

Comment: What are you expecting instead?

Comment: You can probably use a `CASE` and build the result that way but I'm not sure what your expected return should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT()` in MySQL.

And if you want to concatenate all the results with the same year into a comma-separated list, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

However, since we need to do two levels of aggregation, once to count all the callsigns for a `NetID`, and then to concatenate all the results for a year, we need to use nested queries.

```
foreach($db_found->query("
        SELECT year, GROUP_CONCAT(obj SEPARATOR ', ') AS obj
        FROM (
            SELECT year(logdate) as year,
                    CONCAT('{ x: new Date(', YEAR(logdate), ', ', MONTH(logdate)-1, ', ', DAY(logdate), '), y: ', COUNT(callsign), ' }') AS obj
              FROM NetLog
             WHERE netcall = 'CARROLL'
               AND netID <> 0
             GROUP BY netID
            ORDER BY logdate) AS x
        GROUP BY year ") as $stat){ 
    switch($stat['year']) {
    case 2017:
        $p2 = $stat['obj'];
        break;
    case 2018:
        $p3 = $stat['obj'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to use `DISTINCT` when using `GROUP BY`, since the grouping ensures that there can never be duplicates.

Comment: This is very nice #Barmar but the only response I get with a echo "$p1 $p3 ]" is; [ { x: new Date(2018,9,8), y: 15 }, ]

Comment: There's no `$p1` in the code, it's `$p2` and `$p3`.

Comment: Sorry, look again I added it to my original code. So sorry man. But did I miss something I really like the simplicity of your answer but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine all the results for the same year.

Comment: Hmmmm!  Now I get; Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function' in /var/www/html/CanvasExamples2.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/CanvasExamples2.php(17): PDO->query('\n\t\tSELECT year...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/CanvasExamples2.php on line 17

Comment: Did the `GROUP_CONCAT` wrong, the delimiter needs the keyword `SEPARATOR` before it.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. You can't use `COUNT(callsign)` inside `GROUP_CONCAT()`, since you can't have one aggregate inside another.

Comment: Now I don't understand your grouping. Do all the rows for the same `netID` have the same `logdate`? If not, your grouping will pick a random `logdate` for each `netID`.

Comment: Every netID has the same date but logdate is a datetimestamp so I need to take it apart. But the date part is always the same.

Comment: I think I've fixed up the query now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181570/discussion-between-keith-d-kaiser-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your code to be simpler:

```
$p1 = " [ ";
$p2 = []; //create empty array
$p3 = []; //create empty array
foreach($db_found->query("SELECT DISTINCT netID, count(callsign) as callcount, year(logdate) as year,
                    month(logdate)-1 as month, day(logdate) as day
      FROM NetLog
     WHERE netcall = 'CARROLL'
       AND netID <> 0

     GROUP BY netID
     ORDER BY logdate ") as $stat) { 

    $x = "new Date($stat[year],$stat[month],$stat[day])";
    $y = "$stat[callcount]";
    $json = "{ x: $x, y: $y },"
    if ($stat[year] == 2017 ){
        $p2[] = $json; //add to array
    } else if ($stat[year] == 2018 ){
        $p3[] = $json; //add to array
    }
}
$p2 = implode(',',$p2); //concat the array elements with ','
$p3 = implode(',',$p3);
```

Comment: #Felippe Duarte I like this new code but it still doesn't output the data correctly. I'll post in my original question what it should look like.

Comment: He's generating JavaScript code that will call `new Date()` on the client. You're calling it on the server.

Comment: Edited. You need to concat the data with previous information. Then you use "implode" to make one string. After that you can add the string to your output the way you need.